# Correlate subscr_id to a Subscription on my PayPal account

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

Is there a way to search a subscription on my business PayPal account based on the unique **subscr_id** sent by PayPal to my server IPN when the user subscribed?
(I believe this detail appear as "Profile" in the Subscription details page)

When a user subscribes to a service on my site I keep record of his details appearing in IPN including **subscr_id**, **payer_email** and **payer_id**. I can also keep record of his **first_name**, **last_name** details.

Each user may have multiple subscriptions. If one day I wish to cancel/suspend/refund a subscription using my business paypal account - how can I detect his subscription?

In the "All activity" PayPal page I see no way to find his unique subscr_id (besides opening all subscriptions one by one), I do not even see his  **payer_email** and **payer_id**, only first and last names which may or may not be unique for a payer. Anyhow, there may be multiple subscriptions per payer - so this is still not a  good solution in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Found it - In the business PayPal account: **MyAccount>History>Basic Search**

Choose "Find a transaction": Paste the **subscr_id** to the search box and choose **"Profile ID"**

Comment: PayPal changes their navigation from time to time. Here is the current location: Log-in and select the "Activity" tab. There is a search field there. You can enter your **subscr_id** and the related entries will populate a list below.